# Setting up Adobe Analytics eCommerce tracking in GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I am currently in the process of setting up Adobe Analytics on a website that is currently using GTM & GA (universal analytics).  Ideally I want to leverage the existing data layer to pass values to the Adobe evars/props but the one question I have was how to handle the products field?  Adobe requires the products field to be in a very specific format (category;product;qty;total).

Can I build this product string in GTM? Or do I need the developers to hard code this string?  I might be overthinking this but I have never installed Adobe thru GTM before

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom javascript variable (GTM "variables" used to be called "macros" which was a lot less confusing) of the type "custom javascript function" to loop through the products array and assemble the product string.

That is you'd first create a dataLayer variable that returns the product array from the dataLayer and then do a loop; a custom javascript variable in GTM is an anonymous function that returns a value. This would look a bit like that (from top of my head, not exact code; the thing in curly brackets is the datalayer products variable you need to create first):

```
function() {
var products = {{products}};
var productAdobe = [];
for(i=0;i<products.length;i++) {
prod = products[i];
productAdobe.push(prod[i].category + ";" + prod[i].id + ";" + prod[i].quantity + ";" + prod[i].quantity*prod[i].price); 
}
return productAdobe.join("\n");
}
```

Like I said this is not exactly working code, but should be enough to give you an idea.

Having said that having your developers pass on a proper product string is a much better idea. Using GTM for programming tasks is error prone and makes maintenance hard (and tag management should make your life easier, not harder). And if you already have Adobe Analytics you should have free Access to Adobe DTM which might a better choice to deploy Adobe Analytics (for one thing you cannot host s_code within GTM, as the custom HTML tag has a length limit that is exceeded by the Adobe Tracking code).

Comment: Thanks for that answer, makes sense. Do you know if you can put DTM inside a GTM container?  The issue is getting access to the developers to get any code implemented

Comment: I will +1 for showing how to do it but I have to disagree with some of this. I think it's better for a data layer to have each component (e.g. product id, price, quantity, etc.) clearly structured in separate components, not tied to the conventions of a single tool. It is a lot easier to loop through a generic array of products than try to parse AA's products string (which the above example is basic; it can get way more complex) to translate to some other tool's convention. My 2 cents anyways

Comment: I would also note that Adobe DTM doesn't offer any built-in/"wizard" way to build a products string either, so you're stuck manually building it regardless. But a good point about not being able to host the core AA lib in GTM. I will say that's a super annoying limitation with GTM :/

Comment: @user2647092 "do you know if you can put DTM inside a GTM container?" No, you should not do this. You should never deploy tag managers through other tag managers.  At best, things get pretty weird and limited with timing and usually you end up having to write custom code for everything and can't use many of the features a tag manager offers.  But a lot of times it will throw errors and may even cause other functionality of your site to stop working. https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/code.html